# Построчное чтение / Readln/Writeln

Tags: delphi

Нужно переделать - готовый код на чтение построчно, используя - Readln/Writeln. Для того что бы не грузить все файлы в память...

```
procedure multiplyStrings(src1, src2, dst: TStrings);
var
  i, j: integer;
begin
  dst.Clear;
  for i := 0 to src1.Count - 1 do
  begin
    for j := 0 to src2.Count - 1 do
    begin
      dst.Add(src1[i] + ';' + src2[j]);
    end;
  end;
end;


var 
  lines1, lines2, destination: TStringList;
begin
  lines1 := TStringList.Create;
  try
    lines2 := TStringList.Create;
    try
      lines1.LoadFromFile('первый файл');
      lines2.LoadFromFile('второй файл');

      destination := TStringList.Create;
      try
        // Вариант первый 
        multiplyStrings(lines1, lines2, destination);
        // Вариант второй
        multiplyStrings(lines2, lines1, destination);

        destination.SaveToFile('новый файл');
      finally
        destination.Fre;
      end;
    finally
      lines2.Free;
    end;
  finally
    lines1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

**Делаю так (но полностью сделать не удается):**

```
procedure TForm1.Button18Click(Sender: TObject);
var
f1,f2,f3:TextFile;
s,str:string;
i:integer;
begin
if OpenDialog1.Execute then begin
AssignFile(f1,OpenDialog1.FileName);
Reset(f1);
if OpenDialog2.Execute then begin
AssignFile(f2,OpenDialog2.FileName);
Reset(f2);
AssignFile(f3, '\Save.txt');
Rewrite(f3);
    while not Eof(f1) do begin

        Readln(f1,s);
        Readln(f2,str);

/// и тут не знаю как цикл переделать как в коде что выше.....?

 Writeln(f3,s);
  end;
CloseFile(f1);
CloseFile(f2);
CloseFile(f3);
end;
end;
end;
```

Comment: @Igor, Создал новую тему...

Comment: А вы сами что либо, кроме копирования чужого кода, пробовали сделать?

Comment: @Владимир Клыков, Пробовал, просто, месяц как начал учить Delphi. И очень тяжело, пока что дается.

Comment: И..? результат? вы строка в строку скопировали код из прошлого запроса.... Это все чему вы за месяц научились? Открытие файла -  `AssignFile` или `FileOpen`  Оба способа позволяют читать текстовый файл построчно, как сделать цикл - в коде из вопроса есть. **подумайте хоть чуть чуть сами, а уже после идите спрашивать на сайт**

Comment: @Владимир Клыков, Добавил свои наработки в вопрос. Оцените и помогите доделать - Пожалуйста.....

Comment: Если исходные файлы трудно загрузить в память, то они порядка гигабайта и содержат примерно 10-100 миллионов строк. А результат будет содержать квадриллион строк... Ещё не поздно остановиться ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if OpenDialog1.Execute and OpenDialog2.Execute then 
begin
  AssignFile(f1,OpenDialog1.FileName);
  AssignFile(f2,OpenDialog2.FileName);

  AssignFile(f3, '\Save.txt');
  Rewrite(f3);

  Reset(f1);
  while not EOF(f1) do
  begin
    ReadLn(f1, s1);
    Reset(f2);
    while not EOF(f2) do
    begin
      ReadLn(f2, s2);

      WriteLn(f3, s1 + ';' + s2);
      // или WriteLn(f3, s2 + ';' + s1);
    end;
    CloseFile(f2);
  end;
  CloseFile(f1);

  CloseFile(f3);
end;
```

Comment: Я на истину не претендую, но разве ReadLn работает как указано у вас? 
`s1 := ReadLn(f1);` помоему(если память не изменяет) у вас в s1 будет или кол-во символов прочитаных уходить или результат(True\False)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков да,  Вы правы. Это, вообще, процедура.

Comment: @Igor, Так в данном случае код не соответствует условию как в вашем коде (я же специально тему новую создал для этого): Вот старая тема ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/916892/Склейка-строк-в-двух-вариантах/916910?noredirect=1#comment1511106_916910

Comment: @Igor может быть, говорил же на истину не претендую, давно таким способом не читал файлы, в основном файловые потоки))

Comment: @Денис Хм, ну поменяйте `s1` и `s2` местами в `WriteLn(f3, s1 + ';' + s2);`.

Comment: @Igor,  Спасибо, получилось, мне еще учить и учить...

Answer (score 2):

```
while not Eof(f1) do 
begin
  Readln(f1,s);
  while not Eof(f2) do
  Begin 
    Readln(f2,str);
    str:=s+';'+str;
    Writeln(f3,str);
  end;
  reset(f2);
end;
```

Comment: Это я знаю, просто я имел в виду что цикл не соответствует условию: ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/916892/Склейка-строк-в-двух-вариантах/916910?noredirect=1#comment1511106_916910

Comment: Вы код смотрели? вывод будет ровно как у вас в первом примере в предыдущем вопросе =) Замените цикл в вашем коде, на этот и посмотрите результат

Comment: Спасибо, получилось, мне еще учить и учить...